# how to update all occurrence of key value

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var someString = "style="height: 247px; width: 329px;" rel="height: 247px; width: 329px;" ";
```

how to update width value from 329px to 500px using regular expression in javascript.

i'm able to get the width value by using

```
reg = /width:\s(\d*)/;
someString.match(reg)[1];
```

but how to update all width values ?

Comment: If you need to update some text, it means you need a `replace` method. And your regex is almost complete, you do not need capturing parentheses, and you can use `\d+` to match one or more digits.

Comment: how to replace all occurrences of width value ? if i try it's replacing only first value

Comment: Use `/g` modifier at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
var someString = "style=\"height: 247px; width: 329px;\" rel=\"height: 247px; width: 329px;\" ";
someString.replace(/width:\s(\d*px)/g,'500px')
```

I am correcting a bit:

```
someString.replace(/width:\s(\d*px)/g,'width: 500px')
```

Here is example: [Click Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/rietykity/26b8x9ku/)